# cron expression to run every 6 months and on second friday of the month

Tags: cron

My cron(Java Quartz job scheduler) expression should get trigger on Jan 9th, 12 PM ( which is second friday of this month) and next schedule should be 6 months from Jan 9th and on second friday of that month and time 12 PM.

Below expression will work as expected ?.

```
*  * 12 ? 1/6 6#2
```

Regards,
DAM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
0 0 12 ? 1-7/6 6#2

0 --> run only at Secs :00
0  --> run only at minute :00
12 --> Runs on 12 noon
?  --> no specific value
1-7/6 --> runs only on months 1 (January) or 7 (July)
6#2 --> Second friday of the month

Next few Schedules

1.  Friday, January 9, 2015 12:00 PM  
2.  Friday, July 10, 2015 12:00 PM  
3.  Friday, January 8, 2016 12:00 PM  
4.  Friday, July 8, 2016 12:00 PM  
5.  Friday, January 13, 2017 12:00 PM
```

Comment: For the benefit of others who may be viewing your answer, would you be able to specify what kind of cron you are using? Are you using the Java Quartz job scheduler, for example? (The reason I ask you to clarify is that the syntax you have used isn't supported by standard cron, at least not yet for recent Linuxes or BSDs. )

Comment: Yes it is Java Quartz job scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

Your `1/6` needs to include the full range to be covered in steps of 6 months.

So for example, `1-7/6` would start at month 1 (January), then go to month 7 (July) as the next scheduled run, because it covers the range from 1-7 in steps of 6.

Your full command should be

```
0 12 8-14 1-7/6 5
```

Interpretation:

`0` = run only at minute :00,
  `12` = run during the hour of noon,
  `8-14` run only during (matching) days of the month from 8-14 (the second Friday must fall only one one of these dates, and the first Friday cannot fall on any of them),
  `1-7/6` run only on months 1 (January) or 7 (July),
   `5` and only on day 5 (which is Friday, since Sunday is indexed with 0 or 7).

Since cron runs only when all of the above are matched, the command will be run at 12 noon on the second Friday of January and of July.

Comment: Joseph, Thanks for your reply. I am modifing your expression as this --> 0 0 12 ? 1-7/6 6#2 . Passed cron validation, So should work.